# In node how to export functions only during dev build for testing?

Tags: node.js, gulp, automated-tests

I created a node app and have some functions in a file.  I want to do testing on them so I am exporting the functions but this is an security issue so is there anyway I only export it when it's dev time only?

Here is what I have:

```
async function AuthenticateHandler(req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response, next) { ... });
function shutdownServer() { ... }
module.exports = {
  AuthenticateHandler,
  shutdownServer
};
```

To build, I currently use Gulp file and provide args to tell it what environment it is building in:

```
task("Build", series(CopyConfig));
function CopyConfig(cb){
    if(arg.env == "dev"){
        return src(['config.dev.json'])
            .pipe(rename("config.json"))
            .pipe(dest('./dist'));
    } else if(arg.env == "prod"){
        return src(['config.prod.json'])
            .pipe(rename("config.json"))
            .pipe(dest('./dist'));
    }else if(arg.env == "local"){
        return src(['config.local.json'])
            .pipe(rename("config.json"))
            .pipe(dest('./dist'));
    }
};
```

How can I only export when in dev and local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use an environment variable, which will be accessible in any file. You could add a script to your `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:dev": "NODE_ENV='development' gulp"
}
```

Then, in your file(s) with the exports, something like this:

```js
async function AuthenticateHandler(req: Restify.Request, res: Restify.Response, next) { ... });
function shutdownServer() { ... }

module.exports.shutdownServer = shutdownServer;

// conditionally export a function
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  module.exports.AuthenticateHandler = AuthenticateHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting an environment variable with the value of the current environment and then put the 'module.exports' in the if block.

```
if(process.env['ENV'] === 'dev'){
    module.exports = {};
}
```